# Where can I find more information about this kind of "pseudo-inverse"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

I have the following matrix:
$$
A = \left[
\begin{array}{llll}
+1 &-1 &+0 &+0\\
+0 &+1 &-1 &+0\\
+1 &+0 &+0 &-1\\ 
\end{array}\right]
$$
for which I verified that the typical right pseudo-inverse $A^{\dagger}=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$ is
$$
A^{\dagger} = \left[
\begin{array}{llll}
+0.50 &+0.25 &+0.25\\
-0.50 &+0.25 &+0.25\\
-0.50 &-0.75 &+0.25\\
+0.50 &+0.25 &-0.75\\
\end{array}\right]
$$
which verifies $AA^{\dagger}=I_{3\times 3}$ with $I_{3\times 3}$ the $3\times 3$ identity matrix.

However, I (manually) found that the matrix
$$
M= \left[
\begin{array}{llll}
2&2&2 \\
1&2&2 \\
1&1&2 \\
2&2&1
\end{array}\right]
$$

also, satisfies $AM=I_{3\times 3}$, and I cant find any relation between $A^{\dagger}$ and $M$. Does anyone know what exactly is $M$ with respect to $A$? Is there another technique to compute a different pseudo-inverse (which will have $M$ as its output) that I am not aware of? am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that finding a right inverse involves solving a system of $9$ linear equations in $12$ unknowns. Hence, there are degrees of freedom.

Comment: You are totally right. There are infinite solutions, and both matrices satisfy that system of equations (As I have verified). It was as simple as that. Thanks.

Comment: Of the matrices that satisfy $A X = I$, $A^{\dagger}$ has the smallest Euclidian norm.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1865950/339790).

Comment: Thanks guys. Those comments clarified a lot to me. This makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by a user comment, $M$ is just a right inverse of $A$. Provided that $B$ is a right inverse of $A$, since $AM=I\Rightarrow A(M-B)=0$, every right inverse of $A$ is in the form $M=B+K$, where $K$ is any matrix such that $AK=0$ (i.e. $K$ is any matrix whose columns lie in the null space of $A$). In your case, as $AA^+$ is indeed equal to $I$, all right inverses of $A$ are in the form of $A^++K$ for some matrix $K$ such that $AK=0$.

Nicholas Higham happened to have blogged about generalised inverse earlier today. You may learn more about Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse from [his blog entry](https://nhigham.com/2020/04/03/what-is-a-generalized-inverse/).