# Reference for $\ell_1$-$\ell_2$ regularization

Tags: optimization, reference-request, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, regularization

Given matrices $A, W \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, consider the following  optimization problem

$$ \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \| W x \|_1 + \| Ax - y \|_2^2,$$

Is there any general optimization framework for this kind of problem? I have found that some papers only deal with the case where $W = I$ (identity matrix). Could anyone give me some references?

Comment: This is called $l_1$ or, in some circles, lasso regularization.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, but from my limited understanding lasso treats $W$ as identity matrix. I want to find out references for general situation.

Comment: Have you tried introducing optimization variables $t_1$ and $t_2$, and then minimizing $t_1 + t_2$ subject to $\| W x \|_1 \leq t_1$ and $\| Ax - y \|_2^2 \leq t_2$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Hi, thanks for your advice. Let me try to formulate this problem as standard form. But how is the $\ell_1$ norm solved?

Comment: @standerQiu Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2157633/339790).

Comment: Did you make any progress?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Hi, sorry for late reply. Busy these days. I find that it is possible to approximate the $\ell_1$ norm as Huber norm ( $\ell_2$ norm close to the non-smooth regions) and then apply the ISTA algorithm for the problem.