# Minimisation of $1$-norm subject to equality constraint

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to solve the following optimisation problems.

$$ \begin{gather} &\begin{array}{ll} \underset {x, y} {\text{minimize}} & |x|+|y| \\ \text{subject to} & 3 x + 2 = y \end{array} \tag{OP$_1$} \\ \\ \\ &\begin{array}{ll} \underset {x, y} {\text{minimize}} & |x|+|y| \\ \text{subject to} & \sin x + x^2 = y\end{array} \tag{OP$_2$} \end{gather}$$

I would be highly obliged for any help, hints or suggestions.

Comment: I am trying toi plot it .I will add some graphs to it for some clues

Comment: Do you agree with my latest edits?

Comment: You can solve OP1 using ADMM (alternating direction method of multipliers).

Comment: These are least-norm problems in 2D in the 1-norm

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2853747/339790)

Comment: For the second, note that the $L_1$-distance can never be negative…

Comment: Would you kindly share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these problems can be solved by using the constraints to eliminate $\ y\ $ from the objective functions. The first is equivalent to
$$
\underset{x}{\text{minimize}}\ |x|+|2+3x|\ ,
$$
and the second to
$$
\underset{x}{\text{minimize}}\ |x|+|x^2+\sin x|\ .
$$
For the objective of the first, we have
$$
|x|+|2+3x|=\cases{-4x-2&if $\ x\le-\frac{2}{3}$\\
                   2+2x&if $\ -\frac{2}{3}<x\le0$\\
                   2+4x&if $\ 0<x\ $,}
$$
which is clearly decreasing  for $\ -\infty<x\le-\frac{2}{3}\ $ and increasing for $\ -\frac{2}{3}\le x\le\infty\ $, and therefore attains its minimum of
$\ \frac{2}{3}\ $ at $\ x=-\frac{2}{3}\ $.

The equation
$$
x^2+\sin x=0
$$
has a unique solution $\ x_0\ $ lying somewhere in the interval $\ \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},0\right)\ $.  The function $\ x^2+\sin x\ $ is negative for $\ x_0<x<0\ $, but non-negative for $\ x\le x_0\ $ and $\ 0<x\ $. Therefore
$$
|x|+|x^2+\sin x|=\cases{x^2+\sin x-x&if $\ x\le x_0$\\
                -x^2-\sin x-x&if $\ x_0<x\le0$\\
                 x^2+\sin x+x&if $\ 0<x\ $.}
$$
While it's not as immediately obvious as in the first case, it's not difficult to show from this that $\ |x|+|x^2+\sin x|\ $ is decreasing  for $\ -\infty<x\le 0\ $ and increasing for $\ 0\le x\le\infty\ $, and therefore attains its minimum of
$\ 0\ $ at $\ x=0\ $.

Answer (score 0):

for first one, you can linearize by couple of constraints defined by 2 additional variables $ x',y'$
$ x \le x'$
$ -x \le x'$
$ y \le y'$
$ -y \le y'$
$3x+2 = y$
Min $ x' + y'$

For OP2, same for the norm but if you want to linearize $\sin(x)$ either you need special constraints from solvers like Gurobi or use piecewise linear functions.

Comment: A graphical estimate may be the best way to get an approximate answer for the second problem. That is, make a graph of $y=x^2+\sin x$ and use this to estimate the closest point (in the L1 sense)…and in fact this is better than an estimate.